# Python: // operator

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python or programming in general. Please describe why is there a difference between the statements of these two results.

```
>>> print 100//18
5
>>> print ((10**2)//9*2)
22
```

Comment: its floor division. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm

Comment: @Nullman The parenthesis evaluates to the same numbers as in the first statement. Then why there is a difference

Comment: like BranBarn said in his answer, division and multiplication have the same precedence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because multiplication and division have the same precedence and are left-associative.  So `100//9*2` means `(100//9)*2`, not `100//(9*2)`.  This is a pretty universal convention in math and isn't specific to Python.  (The fact that you're using `10**2` instead of `100` is immaterial here.)  If you do `100//(9*2)` you'll again get 5.

Comment: I am using for loop for print a numerical triangle. That is why I am using ((10**i)//9*i). Thanks for the answer it is clear.